# Unable to get cached AJAX data dimensions

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I'm trying to make my AJAX calls more efficient by caching data that has already been AJAXed. I also need to render the data in a certain way depending on the some of the resulting data's dimensions.

When calling the data for the first time, the dimensions can be read, and all is well. The cache also works well enough, but I'm having a huge amount of difficulty getting the dimensions of elements within cached data.

Below is a simplified version of what I'm doing (with identical problems):

```
var cache = {};

// The AJAX part
function getDetails(request){
    return jQ.get(request);
};

// Filter & render AJAX data
function renderData(data){
    var endResult = $(data).find('#theTargetElement');
    endResult.appendTo($placehold);
    $placehold.find('#theTargetElement').css('visibility','hidden');
    // This will log the dimensions on AJAX data fine
    // But almost all cached data returns height 0
    console.log( height of certain elements within data );
};

// Click handler
jQ('#slides').on('click', '.slideLink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = jQ(this).attr("href");
    if ( cache[target] ) { // If the data exists in cache object
        var $cached = cache[target]
        renderData( $cached );
    } else {
        getDetails(target)
            .done( function(result) {
                cache[target] = result;
                renderData(result);
            })
    }
});
```

The appended data is definitely there and appears on the page - I just can't seem to use its measurements.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you end up with multiple elements with the "id" equal to "theTargetElement", but there's something I don't understand about the code. Is there code you are not showing that removes the element that's append in `renderData` from the page? If not, why do you need to re-append it from the cache?

Comment: I can see why you might think that, given the included code, but "theTargetElement" is always removed from the placeholder before another instance of the click handler fires. So there's never two elements with the same id present.